# How can I prove that $a^{2}\leq(\frac{2ab}{a+b})^{2}\leq ab\leq(\frac{a+b}{2})^{2}\leq b^{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How can I prove that? 
$$0<a\leq b$$
$$a^{2}\leq(\frac{2ab}{a+b})^{2}\leq ab\leq(\frac{a+b}{2})^{2}\leq b^{2}$$

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$? What is the relationship between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: It appears this is true precisely when $a \leq b$.

Comment: Of course, it is not true that $ab < 0$.

Comment: sorry! $$0<a\leq b$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the first :

> $$a\leq b$$

\begin{eqnarray}
a+b&\leq& 2b\\
(a+b)^2&\leq& (2b)^2\\
a^2(a+b)^2 &\leq& (2ab)^2\\
a^2&\leq& \left(\frac{2ab}{a+b}\right)^2 
\end{eqnarray}
for the second we know that

> $$
> 0\leq (a-b)^2 
> $$

so

\begin{eqnarray}
2ab&\leq& a^2+b^2\\
2ab+2ab&\leq& a^2+b^2+2ab\\
4ab&\leq& (a+b)^2\\
4ab\times ab &\leq &ab(a+b)^2 \\
(2ab)^2 &\leq & ab(a+b)^2 \\
 \left(\frac{2ab}{a+b}\right)^2 &\leq & ab
\end{eqnarray}
for the third inequality we have :

> $$0\leq (a-b)^2$$

\begin{eqnarray}
2ab\leq& a^2+b^2\\
4ab\leq& (a+b)^2\\
ab\leq& \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2 
\end{eqnarray}
the last one we have we can deduce it directly from the mean inequality :
$$
a\leq b \; \implies \; a\leq \frac{a+b}{2} \leq b
$$
so

> $$a \leq b $$

\begin{eqnarray}
a+b \leq& 2b \\
\frac{a+b}{2} \leq& b \\
\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2 \leq& b^2
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

Last one $$b^{2}-(\frac{a+b}{2})^{2}= (b+ \frac{a+b}{2})(b-\frac{a+b}{2}) = (\frac{a+2b}{2})(\frac{b-a}{2}) \geq 0 $$ since $b\geq a, a,b>0$ then 
$$ b^{2} - (\frac{a+b}{2})^{2}\geq 0\Leftrightarrow (\frac{a+b}{2})^{2}\leq b^{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Second one: $$ 0\leq (a-b)^2 \Leftrightarrow 4ab \leq a^2 + 2ab +b^2 \Leftrightarrow \frac{4ab}{(a+b)^2} \leq 1 \Leftrightarrow (\frac{2ab}{a+b})^{2}\leq ab$$